# AC sweep and Dc sweep help in Lt spice?

Tags: mosfet, motor, ltspice, h-bridge

I built a H bridge circuit and I'm struggling with the analysis part.
Below is the H bridge circuit I built .A brief description of the circuit:  V1 and V2 both send inverse PWM signals and U1 and U2 are both optocoupler where U3,U4,U5,U6 are MOSFET and the circuit is being powered by a 7.2 voltage supply.

[image]

The issues I'm having is how can i run a DC sweep to investigate the minimum Dc operating point especially when the battery is low.
How can i run a AC sweep of the input source.

Comment: How would you decide the minimum DC operating point? What exactly would you look at in order to determine that? That's important to know, first. Also, may I assume you already know about .STEP and .MEAS cards?

Comment: @jonk this is the only information my teacher has given me bullet point 3d. https://imgur.com/a/LbilBl5   I know about step but not MEAS i will look it up

Comment: You can use .STEP PARAM to change a variable value. You can use a LIST or a other means to change the values. Then make sure you use {} to surround your expression when writing it into the device (like an inductor) value. So, for example, if the PARAM name is MYL then you would place {MYL} as the value for the inductor.

Comment: Ok thanks i get this now how should i set up the step response for investigate the minimum Dc operating point.